# blockdev command: what is maximum sectors per request?

Tags: kernel, hard-disk, command, io, block-device

`blockdev` has this option `--getmaxsect` to "get max sectors per request". **BLOCKDEV(8)** manual page however doesn't state what max sectors per request means.

I ran this command on my system and I got the following results:

```
# blockdev --getmaxsect /dev/sda
2560
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`blockdev` is a basic interface to the block device `ioctl`s; in `--getmaxsect`’s case, it uses [`BLKSECTGET`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/block/ioctl.c#n551), which returns the maximum number of sectors for a request in the queue associated with the block device. There doesn’t seem to be much documentation on this; [`include/linux/blkdev.h`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/include/linux/blkdev.h#n317) is relevant. It is mentioned briefly in [chapter 12 of *Linux Device Drivers*, 2nd edition](http://www.xml.com/ldd/chapter/book/ch12.html):

> **`BLKSECTGET`**
> **`BLKSECTSET`**
>
> These commands retrieve and set the maximum number of sectors per request (as stored in `max_sectors`).

In summary, `blockdev --getmaxsect` returns the maximum number of sectors which can be used in a single request to the block device.